# cypress mocha test on windows machine

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, ui-automation, cypress

I am using cypress on windows 10 machine. Script works perfectly fine on mac. I am not able to go to home page. This is the code

file1.js:

```
it("Loads an homepage", () => {
// Open up the homepage

cy.visit("/something?Id=more&view=1");
}
```

Base url is http://localhost:1234
I run it through cypress test runner and this is what open

http://localhost:1234/__/#/tests/integration\file1.js

Am not sure why it does not read link from the file? i have tried changing the slashes but it does not work.

Pls advise

Note : Base url works perfectly fine and also the page url which I want to visit works perfectly fine